# count number of consecutive cells meeting a condition

Tags: excel-formula

In a spreadsheet, I want to count the number of consecutive rows that are meeting a condition. The counting should stop once the condition is breached.

Ex: I want to find how many rows have a number below 10 consecutively in the following data set, until a number greater than 10 appears.
8,7,11,2,3,4,6,5

In the above case, i want my answer to be 2 (and not 7), because i want the counting to stop right at the cell where 11 appears. For a better understanding of my question, please refer this [**Screenshot with comments**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjY5A.png).

Please let me know if there is any formula to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Let us know what you have tried so for

Comment: I tried =countif(A2:A9,"<10"), but as the function counts all the numbers, it is not ignoring the count when it comes across 11. What i'm unable to achieve with that formula is: 
1. to ensure the numbers are consecutively meeting the condition, 
2. to stop counting when the condition is breached

Answer (score 0):

try this...

Place `=IF(A1<=10,1,0)` in cell `C1`

Place `=IF(IF(AND(A2<=10,A1<=10),1+B1,0)=0,IF(A2<=10,1,0),IF(AND(A2<=10,A1<=10),1+B1,0))` in `C2` and drag it tell your last cell.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Praveen. But that partially solves my problem. Have placed a screenshot in the question for a better understanding of my exact need.

Comment: I am not sure whether that can be done through formula